# ¿Cómo enviar un archivo adjunto con phpMailer?

Tags: php

Tengo un problema al enviar un archivo adjunto usando `phpmailer`.

Ejemplo tengo formulario de trabaja con nosotros y la idea es que cuando el usuario adjunte su `CV` este le llegue a un correo en específico.

Actualmente así estoy recibiendo los datos:

```
$data = array();
    $data['nombre']             = html_entity_decode($_POST['nombre'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8");
    $data['celular']            = html_entity_decode($_POST['celular'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8");
    $data['email']              = html_entity_decode($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8");
    $data['cargo']              = html_entity_decode($_POST['cargo'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8");


    $archivo['archivo']   =  $_FILES['archivo']; 

    $id                         = $db->insert('trabaja', $data);
```

Así lo mando a la función `mail`:

```
 if ($_POST['nombre']) {
    $mensaje = enviarCorreo($data['nombre'],  $data['celular'], $data['email'], $data['cargo'], $archivo['archivo']);
} else {
    $mensaje = false;
    echo 'Presenta un problema. Intente ingresar los datos nuevamente.';
}
```

y dentro de la función estoy mandando así los datos:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->From     = 'test@test.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Trabaja con Nosotros';
$mail->Subject  = $asunto;
$mail->MsgHTML($contenido);
$mail->AddCC('mi@mail.com');
$mail->AddAttachment($archivo);
```

Me pueden orientar en que estoy haciendo mal ... Actualmente solo me llegan los datos de los usuarios **(nombre, celular, mail y cargo)**, pero llega sin adjunto.

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11764230/236345) en SO original, podrías probar con

```
if (isset($_FILES['archivo']) &&
    $_FILES['archivo']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['archivo']['name']);
}
```

Pues la definición del método para añadir adjuntos es:

```
public function AddAttachment($path,
                              $name = '',
                              $encoding = 'base64',
                              $type = 'application/octet-stream')
```

Y requiere tanto el nombre temporal del archivo al subirlo, como el nombre que le quieres dar al mismo cuando lo adjuntas.

Comment: @Aprendiz pues la tercera acepción de Original en la RAE es "Dicho de cualquier objeto: Que ha servido como modelo para hacer otro u otros iguales a él.". Entonces sí, SO en español no es original porque no es el sitio originario :).

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, probe con esa solución y no pasa nada sigue llegando vacío. Creo que mi error debe estar en cómo recibo el archivo y como lo mando a la función mail

Comment: @Nicolas podrías añadir una validación en la que, si el if propuesto no se cumple, registres algo en el log o en alguna parte para saber si es que no tienes archivo disponible para adjuntar. Por favor, revisa además los logs de apache

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

**Formulario html**:

```
 <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="post" id="form-trabaja">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre completo" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Nombre completo'" required  onkeypress="return alfabetico(event);">

    <input type="text" name="celular" id="celular" placeholder="Celular" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Celular'" required onkeypress="return isNumber(event);" maxlength="9">

    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Email'" required class="single-input">

    <input type="text" name="cargo" id="cargo" placeholder="Área de Interés" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Área de Interés'" required onkeypress="return alfabetico(event);">

    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" placeholder="Curriculum" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Curriculum'" >

    <button name="enviar-trabaja" name="enviar-trabaja" type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**JS:**
En este punto agregue todas las validaciones del formulario antes de que se envien los datos:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#enviar-trabaja").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#form-trabaja").submit();
    });


    $("#form-trabaja").validate({
        rules: {
            nombre: {
                required: true
            },
            celular: {
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                emailExt: true
            },
            cargo: {
                required: true
            },
            file: {
                required: true
            }
        },

        messages: {
            nombre: "Ingrese Nombre",
            apellido: "Ingrese Apellido",
            celular: {
                required: "Ingrese Número Celular"
            },
            email: {
                required: "Ingrese Email",
                email: "Ingrese un Email válido"
            },
            cargo: {
                required: "Ingrese Área de Interés"
            },
            file: {
                required: false
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $('#enviar-trabaja').attr("disabled", true);
            enviarFormTrabaja();
        }   
    });
});
```

Dentro del mismo JS una vez se validen todos los campos se activa la siguiente función:

```
    function enviarFormTrabaja(){

    $( 'form' ).submit(function ( e ) {
        var form = $('form')[0];
        var formData = new FormData(form);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'trabaja.php',
                data: formData,
                processData: false, 
                contentType: false,
                type: "POST",

                success: function (data){
                    document.location.href = "respuesta.html";
                }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Una vez se ejecutada la función se envían los datos por AJAX a mi archivo .php dónde recibo el archivo y los datos de la siguiente forma:

```
if (isset($_POST['nombre']) != null) { 

    $db->connect(); 

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Santiago');

    ini_set('display_errors',true);

    $hoy = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $ip = get_client_ip_env();

    $path = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $tamanio = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $tipo = $_FILES['file']['type'];

        $data = array();
        $data['nombre']             = html_entity_decode($_POST['nombre'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8");
        $data['celular']            = html_entity_decode($_POST['celular'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8");
        $data['email']              = html_entity_decode($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8");
        $data['cargo']              = html_entity_decode($_POST['cargo'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8");
        $data['fecha_registro']     = $hoy;
        $data['ip']                 = $ip;



        $id                         = $db->insert('trabaja', $data);
//    INSERT DATOS DEL FORMULARIO DE CONTACTO


    $db->disconnect(); // Luego de insertar se cierra la BD

    if ($_POST['nombre']) {
        $mensaje = enviarCorreo($data['nombre'],  $data['celular'], $data['email'], $data['cargo'], $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);
    } else {
        $mensaje = false;
        echo 'Presenta un problema. Intente ingresar los datos nuevamente.';
    }
}
```

Una vez insertados los datos dentro de mi base de datos (No inserto datos de los archivos porque no necesito guárdalos solo quiero enviarlos a un usuario) se activa la función de enviar correo donde mando todos los campos del formulario y para el **archivo adjunto** solo mando tmp_name (archivo en cuestión) y name (nombre del archivo).

La función de envío de correo dentro del PHP queda de esta forma:

```
function enviarCorreo($nombre, $celular, $email, $cargo, $path, $name)
{
    include_once('includes/class.phpmailer.php');
    include_once('includes/class.smtp.php');

    $ip = get_client_ip_env();


    $asunto    = "Formulario Trabaja";
    $contenido = "
            <b>Nombre: </b>"     .$nombre. "<br />
            <b>E-mail: </b>"   .$email. "<br />
            <b>Celular: </b>"   .$celular. "<br />
            <b>Cargo: </b>"   .$cargo. "<br />
            ";

    $contenido .= "
            <br /><br /><small>IP de envío: ".$ip." </small>
            <br /><small>Este correo ha sido generado automáticamente.</small>
            ";

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    // $mail->Port = 465;
    // $mail->CharSet  = "UTF-8";
    $mail->From     = 'correo desde el cual envías';
    $mail->FromName = 'Trabaja con Nosotros';
    $mail->Subject  = $asunto;
    $mail->MsgHTML($contenido);
    $mail->AddAddress('correo a quien quieres que le lleguen los datos');
    $mail->AddCC('copia de correo');
    $mail->AddAttachment( $path, $name);


    if ($mail->Send()) {
        $mensaje = true;
    } else {
        $mensaje = false;
    }

    return $mensaje;
}
```

Con esto funciono sin problemas.

Comment: Hola Nicolas, el javascript lo colocaste dentro del body directamente o creaste un -js aparte y luego lo llamaste como un script?